# buffering calls to ajax and sql

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sqlite

My situation is a PHP script that has HTML select tags.  When the onchange from the select happens it can fire off up to 15 javascript functions, each slightly different.  Each function has an AJAX call to a PHP script (no HTML in this script) and returns a PHP echo that is used as a .responseText to change an element in the document.

That all works fine and fast, but I do suspect that the order in which the functions are processed is arbitrary, though this is not important.

What I am trying to do now is to include in the PHP script that is called by the AJAX call a SQL UPDATE into a database.  This is where the whole thing appears to be falling over it's own feet as I am getting only some SQL statements generated, and not the one I want anyway since, from the, say, 15 functions fired off initially only up to 7 should be generating SQL statements.

Any ideas on buffering AJAX calls?

Comment: Is it possible to share the PHP script where you are adding SQL UPDATE? May be with that we can help you better.

Comment: If you are using jquery you could chain them using the complete callback function? I would look to use that in combination with iterating through a call stack of the SQL update functions. Easier to advise though as Vanga indicates if you post your code.